# need help decoding

Tags: cryptography

i am trying to decode this data but have no idea where to start. any help would be greatly appreciated

4,2,93eba2404abd4eaca468c828178cf3af,B005,167c5351,16852f43,27c,0,l6VERmVDGmY/YdIbPo5lUODp418=
4,2,2700638c948c41bb9c0a660b97571a3d,B005,167318d7,167bf4c3,27c,0,n3ew0OWbkHW6Pf3CaOwe675cj9o=
4,2,5e5f918faf73473eaaad791188b3157b,B005,1669e05a,1672ba43,27c,0,sj9N53Bwb7RN6yc4i+NT77cJYxk=
4,2,54e0cc108f0c49248e29cf06cba6a572,B005,16269429,162f6fb3,27c,0,XcA3gtDeqtcbxrKnQhLwHCxtxUQ=
4,2,e6976a0aaa3745af9abb3f0b3d0b3a41,B005,161d4222,16263533,27c,0,m0jD3iyOwmPQQDJkPClDk7WPzsY=
4,2,42c98a71bde747e4972bfaaa814b0e75,B005,1601abe7,160a85b3,27c,0,PGphTgw12axH40TsvT2fTLnYgsg=
4,2,8ed3702fe29b4be48d5f77964060a17c,B005,15f9c3b0,16029cb3,27c,0,6285cq7kDHVGGDoMJw/EbObfwmo=
4,2,4a9831b0c19f496cada2f15a1e45f20a,B005,15f08880,15f96233,27c,0,4E1WVp81gGPpO2S2lFdq4exZKqA=
4,2,e227eb9e9fa24f778062098681e1fdf4,B005,15e5fc6c,15eed633,27c,0,uHhVJZ2gEkOArWb6EZYCgs4CAlE=
4,2,d19805d852694e6093fcc5d01491d8b0,B005,15dcc1f3,15e59bb3,27c,0,tYDudlh3EtVQQ9ARaHBql7YgbmI=
4,2,9bedf593e6be4e88819a48012ddd268a,B005,1660a5c0,16697fc3,27c,0,qG3cSVwBcUrIDLT21IJNIEr279Q=
4,2,20fcabee3d0041c4ab78f54b7a77b725,B005,165751f0,16604543,27c,0,XGd3DTm3tZ5AJ3AcR5AHIH79acY=
4,2,073f62fa62d1445fa73b7d2ac8281f49,B005,164b8fd6,165467c3,27c,0,vqHiRMdCUSrN9BZqYD8IUyNJm3c=
4,2,ec0d102c4d974fb8811b0fc1b8df072f,B005,16390ad4,1641f2c3,27c,0,FJgiOuA1TVDV4edJ9AtDJ+uxYHk=
4,2,1325011e1fbe459abd95324f1f483234,B005,162fce3a,1638aa33,27c,0,Q64baWBI1LtLAscVkWn/xeG6oLI=

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a decoding service.

Comment: And are you sure that's encrypted? It just looks like encoding to me.